# Does gboard have a key to switch keyboard apps?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I am looking for a way to quickly switch between keyboard apps while using gboard. My phone is a redmi 5.

For e.g if I am writing a message I prefer gboard. But when I have to write code I want to quickly switch to hackers keyboard app.

Incidentally on the latter I have the option to jump back to gboard...

I want to be sure that there is no option on gboard to do the same.

Comment: Try long-pressing the spacebar?

Comment: @Andrew T. Not OP, but that's failing for me on 8.1.0 with Gboard + Hacker's Keyboard installed. There is a notification (from Android System) that pops up while focused in a text input when there's more than one keyboard enabled that allows switching between them easily though.

Comment: @AndrewT. That helped. Not complaining. But I think this should be a separate question on its own. The question linked to by the close-vote only deals with switching languages - not the keyboard app as such. But I would want to close this for accepting answers...

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, though as a long-time Gboard user, the globe icon and long-pressing spacebar will also show other keyboard apps, in addition to switching languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press and hold the spacebar while using Gboard to switch languages and keyboards.

Comment: Funny.  This was not what I tried... I thought you were referring to the globe like icon left of spacebar...

Comment: Oops. I think you can also press and hold your keyboard? I'll have to try Hacker's keyboard once and see how can I switch keyboards.

Comment: Yes, you can press and hold the spacebar in your Gboard to switch keyboards, lemme edit my answer

Comment: if someone wonder, **you can switch from hacker keyboard by long pressing the round key** (the one used to open the settings)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, because I don't like going into my settings all the time, so I searched and downloaded Keyboard Switcher app from F-droid.